# SSIS Connection Manager - Use files with Different Names, same structure

Tags: ssis

i am getting two text file having same structure with different name every time.
and i need to load the file everytime to table. how can we configure our connection manager
to load data from different file name to a table. Please any one suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FileName` variable in your Flat File Connection Manager's `ConnectionString` property and dynamically set it to the different name(s) and achieve this.

[image]

Here's a detailed article that shows you step-by-step on how to accomplish this.

[SSIS - Dynamically set Flat File Connection Manager](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11113/ssis-dynamically-set-flat-file-connection-manager.aspx)